# ActiveMq does not stop if broker is not available

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jmx, messagebroker

Getting the below error while stopping the Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.6. Setting the `createConnector="false"` becuase do not want default JMX connection.
Note:- Start the ActiveMQ(activemq-admin.bat start)
       Stop the ActiveMQ(activemq-admin.bat stop)

```
<managementContext createConnector="false"/>
```

Error:

> Connecting to JMX URL:
>   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi INFO: Broker not
>   available at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi

Comment: Where is the error coming from (e.g. client or server)? Some context would help.

Comment: I am starting and stopping  the ActiveMQ using batch script(activemq-admin.bat start and activemq-admin.bat stop)

Comment: This problem, i am facing at server side. – @JustinBertram

Comment: maybe the method activemq-admin is stopping the server is JMX ? If so, you need to enable JMX (or find another way to stop the server ...)

Comment: I can not enable JMX. So, finding that another way to stop the server. @Axel Podehl

Comment: ok - what is the issue with starting JMX ? If your concerns are about security, please note that you could configure JMX to be using your local interface only (127.0.0.1)

Comment: @AxelPodehl - I agree with your point that i can configure JMX using local interface only. But it should not mandatory that ActiveMQ does not stop untill JMX is not enable.

Comment: Well, somehow you need to tell that Java process (the ActiveMQ Broker) that it should stop. You could send a signal on Unix, or use taskkill on windows, or send a JMX request (preferred) or maybe send a JMS message to shut it down.